# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "24 pm"

Tags: java, android, numberformatexception

My app crashed when I choose time using a TimePicker.
How to fix this?

Please guide me.

when I print the `timeMinute` `System.out: 30 am` I get an 
error on this line `Integer.parseInt(timeMinute.replace(" am","")), true);`

```
start_time.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);

        start_time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String time = start_time.getText().toString();

                if (time != null && !time.equals("")) {
                    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(time, ":");
                    String timeHour = st.nextToken();
                    String timeMinute = st.nextToken();

                    timePickDialog = new TimePickerDialog(v.getContext(),
                            new TimePickHandler(), Integer.parseInt(timeHour),
                            Integer.parseInt(timeMinute.replace(" am","")), true);

                } else {
                    timePickDialog = new TimePickerDialog(v.getContext(),
                            new TimePickHandler(), 10, 45, true);
                }
                timePickDialog.show();
            }
        });



private class TimePickHandler implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            //start_time.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
            int hour = hourOfDay % 12;
            if (hour == 0)
                hour = 12;
            start_time.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d %s", hour, minute,hourOfDay < 12 ? "am" : "pm"));
            timePickDialog.hide();
        }

    }
```

Comment: well you only replace `am` but you have an input with `pm`

Comment: how to replace both of them ? @Japu_D_Cret

Comment: as your title shows 24 pm is not a valid int.Try to remove pm from this.

Comment: @Rotwang i want to replace the am and pm but the replace not working

Comment: Just add `.replace(" pm","")` after the replace " am"

Comment: if you want to make it in one line, you could use `timeMinute.replaceAll("( am)|( pm)", "")`, which uses the RegEx replace

Comment: or `timeMinute.replaceAll("\s[a|p]m", "")`

Comment: thanks dude its working @Japu_D_Cret

Comment: @Rotwang: Please write answers in the answers section. A brief answer is not necessarily a poor one.

Comment: @Bathsheba ... too late! ;)

Comment: There's no harm in your answering now. Stack Overflow works best when there are multiple answers to choose from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following :

```
if (time != null && !time.equals("")) {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(time, ":");
    String timeHour = st.nextToken();
    String timeMinute = st.nextToken();

    timePickDialog = new TimePickerDialog(v.getContext(),
        new TimePickHandler(), Integer.parseInt(timeHour),
        Integer.parseInt(timeMinute.replace(" am","").replace(" pm","")), true);
}
```

to replace both " am" and " pm" with "".

Comment: Or using a regular expression: `timeMinute.replaceAll("\s[a|p]m", "")`

Comment: @Rotwang True, even if not every programmer is familiar with regex, so `.replace()` might be easier to understand.  Still your solution is shorter.

Comment: Well, also the `replace()` solution is "mine", if you see in the comments, that one  was the first thing I suggested... ;)

Comment: I saw that right after validating my solution post. SO warns you when you're writing a solution and someone posts a solution in the mean time, but not when useful comments are written. I upvoted both your comments.

Comment: Meh. Always put answers in the answers section. Comments are the poor cousin of answers as they are not subjected to the same peer review process. There's no harm in taking comments as an *inspiration* for an answer although I would refrain from explicit plagiarism - there is no evidence for the latter in this good answer.

Answer (score 4):

A shorter solution, just to provide an alternative to using a double `replace()`, would be to use a Regular Expression:

```
timePickDialog = new TimePickerDialog(v.getContext(),
    new TimePickHandler(), Integer.parseInt(timeHour),
    Integer.parseInt(timeMinute.replace("\s[a|p]m", ""), true);
```